# How do I make this select query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a `SELECT` query in mysql.

There are two tables, `users` and `image_info`, and need to select following columns.

user table : `user_id, username, dob`

image_info : `image, image_path`

When selecting image. I need to get only primary image from image_info table. In image_info table there is a column like:

> image_type ENUM('primary', 'gallery') DEFAULT NULL,

This is how I tried it..

```
$q = "SELECT u.user_id, u.username, u.dob, i.image, i.image_path
            FROM users u 
                INNER JOIN image_info i ON i.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE u.sex = 'Male'
            ORDER BY u.date_registered DESC LIMIT 6";
```

But it doesn't work properly to get my expected output.

**UPDATE:** 
my table outputs..

```
mysql> select user_id, username, sex from users;
+---------+-------------+--------+
| user_id | username    | sex    |
+---------+-------------+--------+
|       1 | thara1234   | Male   |
|       2 | root234     | Male   |
|       3 | kamal123    | Female |
|       4 | Nilantha    | Male   |
|       5 | Ruwan324324 | Male   |
+---------+-------------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select user_id, image, image_type from image_info;
+---------+----------------------------+------------+
| user_id | image                      | image_type |
+---------+----------------------------+------------+
|       2 | 2_root234_1433564588.jpg   | primary    |
|       1 | 1_thara1234_1433555104.jpg | primary    |
|       1 | 1_thara1234_1433556481.jpg | gallery    |
|       4 | 4_Nilantha_1433573768.jpg  | primary    |
+---------+----------------------------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Thank you.

Comment: So what do you get exactly, and what's the expected output ?

Comment: You can add another filter to the query statement `AND i.image_type='primary'`

Comment: So why you didn't filtered it like `... WHERE u.sex = 'Male' AND i.image_type='primary' ...`

Comment: @mdh.heydari `YOU HAVE AN ERROR IN YOUR SQL SYNTAX`

Comment: If image_table have both primary and gallery images to this selected user. My query get all records. But I want if primary image is available for this selected user just I need to get that image along with my select query..

Comment: @Alex I forgot the punctuation, fixed

Comment: @Alex, Yes I can add a filter like you mention. But problem is if a user doesn't have a primary image then I cann't get that user..

Comment: Have you tried `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: @mdh.heydari `LEFT JOIN` wont do anything as the OP want to get user details either if there is no image type or both types.

Comment: @Alex why not? It gives null values if there was no result on the right side.

Comment: @MCC please be more clear on what output are you expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, query would be :-

```
SELECT User.user_id, User.username, User.dob, Image.image, Image.image_path
FROM 
    users User LEFT JOIN image_info Image
    ON User.user_id = Image.user_id AND Image.image_type = 'PRIMARY'
WHERE User.sex= 'Male'
ORDER BY User.date_registered DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: As you mentioned _If image_table have both primary and gallery images to this selected user. My query get all records. But I want if primary image is available for this selected user just I need to get that image along with my select query_ it would get the associated records as per `users`, from `image_info` table where image type is PRIMARY

Comment: @MCC you have to use `LEFT JOIN` and `Image.image_type = 'PRIMARY'` needs to be shifted to  `ON` instead of `WHERE` , see my updated answer

Comment: Great!! then make sure to choose it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you need the user either he has an image or not you should use left join in your query:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, u.dob, i.image, i.image_path
            FROM users u 
                LEFT JOIN image_info i ON i.user_id = u.user_id
            WHERE u.sex = 'Male' and (i.image_type = 'primary' or i.image_type is null)
            ORDER BY u.date_registered DESC LIMIT 6;
```

[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) for more information.